# Why does this if statement get evaluated true?

Tags: c++

[image]

I just don't get it. The second if statement gets evaluated true. You can see the debug information in the image. If I use `k` in the if statement, it behaves as I would expect. Why is this? Thank you.

Comment: Because you are subtracting two `size_t` (i.e. unsigned) types.

Comment: Paste Code not screenshots

Comment: I paste code. I put a screenshot here so you can see the debug info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size()` returns a `std::vector<int>::size_type` type which is guaranteed by the C++ standard to be an `unsigned` type.

The difference between two `unsigned` types is itself `unsigned`. You are experiencing common *wrap-around* behaviour, and the final value is greater than 2.

In your case you should refactor to `highers.size() >= 2 + lowers.size()` instead. **Never** use subtraction with `unsigned` types, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Ehh.. should have thought of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... almost ...  unsigned types fell for Chuck Norris ;)

Answer (score 6):

It is evaluated to `true` because `size()` returns [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is an *unsigned* type.

When you subtract unsigned `1` from unsigned `0`, you get a big positive number, which is bigger then `2`, of course.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the other answer because of the useful refactor suggestion.